# Is there such thing as 'didGet' in Swift? A method that is run whenever a variable is accessed?

Tags: swift

Basically, I want to do like this:

```
var counter : Int = 0;
private var _data : String;
var data : String {
    get { counter += 1; return _data; }
    set { _data = newValue; }
}
```

Then I want to reduce it like this:

```
var counter : Int = 0;
var data : String {
    get { counter += 1; return data; }
    set { data = newValue; }
}
```

But I noticed that this can't be done. (Error: Variable used within its initial value). So I then want to simplify it like this:

```
var counter : Int = 0;
var data : String {
    didGet { counter += 1; }
}
```

But there's no such thing as `didGet`. Is there any way to do this without adding new other variable? I need to run `counter += 1` every time `data` is accessed, without adding new variable as storage. Thanks.

Comment: I would advise against introducing side effects to a property getter; it makes for a confusing API.

Comment: @Hamish this is for internal debugging, and is not intended to be used by other people. I need to run some specific debugging process when the counter hits certain number, so rather than I add `counter += 1` code each time the `data` is accessed throughout the app (and this is a frequently accessed property), this will be a nice hack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, there is no way to do it without adding new variable.

If you return in the `get` method of the variable the same variable, you will create *infinite loop*.